# Product of Sobolev functions

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $\Omega$ is 2-dimensional bounded open set with smooth boundary and  $f\in W^{2,2}( \Omega) $ and $ g,h\in W^{1,2} ( \Omega) $. What can we say about the regularity of the product of these three functions $ f\cdot  g \cdot h $. I don't believe that it is even a $W^{1,2} $ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is not in $H^1$:

(1) $fgh\in L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p<\infty$ due to the Sobolev embeddings into the $L^q$ spaces

(2) the limiting terms are the products of type $fg\nabla h$, $f\nabla gh$, which are in $L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p<2$ ($f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, $\nabla g\in L^2(\Omega)$, $h\in L^q(\Omega)$ $\forall q<\infty$ implies that the product $f\nabla gh$ is in $L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p<2$).

Answer (score 7):

Due to the embeddings $W^{2,2}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $W^{1,2}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^p(\Omega)$ with any $p\in (2,\infty)$, by Hölder's inequality it readily follows that the product $f\cdot g\cdot h\in W^{1,q}(\Omega)$ with any $q\in [1,2)$. In terms of the Sobolev space $W^{1,q}(\Omega)$, the regularity of the product cannot be stronger, *i.e.*, $f\cdot g\cdot h\not\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, which is corroborated by routine example:
$$
\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\colon |x|<e^{-1}\}, \quad f\equiv 1, \,\,
g(x)=h(x)=\Bigl(\ln{\frac{1}{|x|}}\Bigr)^{1/4} \;\forall\,x\in \Omega,
$$ 
where $\,g,h\in  W^{1,2}(\Omega)\,$ while $\,g\cdot h\not\in  W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

The best known regularity result for the product in question can be formulated in terms of the Orlicz space due to the Trudinger's theorem 8.27 in Adams–Fournier's textbook of *Sobolev Spaces* http://bookza.org/book/492535/11bd42 (see page 277 therein), which implies the embedding $W^{1,2}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L_A(\Omega)$ into the Orlicz space $L_A(\Omega)$ with an $N$-function $A(t)=e^{t^2}-1$. Hence, there is some constant $c>0$ such that the product 
$\varphi\overset{\rm def}{=}f\cdot g\cdot h$ does satisfy the condition
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}e^{c|\varphi(x)|}dx<\infty
$$ 
due to the embedding $\, W^{2,2}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C(\overline{\Omega})\,$ along with an obvious inequality $\,2|g\cdot h|\leqslant g^2+h^2$ followed by applying Hölder's inequality to a product of exponential functions.